# Get the hierarchy (Parent-Child) of a directory with folders and files

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How to get a Parent-Child relationship or Tree from a directory with folders and files.

Given the following directory:

```
Root  
└───folder1
│   │   file011.txt
│   │   file012.txt
│   │
│   └───subfolder1
│       │   file111.txt
│       │   file112.txt
│       │   ...
│   
└───folder2
    │   file021.txt
    │   file022.txt
```

Item holds the information, it can be a folder or a file.

```cs
public class Item
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Item> Children { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
        public bool isDirectory{ get; set; }
}
```

I basically want a function which returns me the desired result in parent-child list.

```cs
var mainDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\RootFolder");

var result = getTreeList(mainDirectory) <-- returns IEnumerable<Item>
```

perhaps LINQ could come in handy??

I tried fiddling around with [EnumerateFileSystemInfos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefilesysteminfos?view=net-6.0) and
[GetFileSystemEntries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfilesystementries?view=net-6.0) but they give me back a flat structure of the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the directory and files recursively, and pass the parent `Item` along in the method, like so:

```cs
Item ReadFilesAndDirectories(string path)
{
    void ReadFilesAndDirectoriesRecursive(string path, Item parent)
    {
        foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            var childDirectoryItem = new Item
            {
                Name = Path.GetDirectoryName(directory),
                IsDirectory = true 
            };

            parent.Children.Add(childDirectoryItem);

            ReadFilesAndDirectoriesRecursive(
                Path.Combine(path, directory), childDirectoryItem);

            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                var childFileItem = new Item
                {
                    Name = Path.GetFileName(file)
                };

                parent.Children.Add(childFileItem);
            }
        }
    }

    var root = new Item { Name = path, IsDirectory = true };
    ReadFilesAndDirectoriesRecursive(path, root);
    return root;
}
```

I have wrapped it in another method that takes care of the initialization of the root directory.

You can then print the directory structure and the files in the following way:

```cs
void PrintItems(Item item, int depth = 0)
{
    foreach (var child in item.Children)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(depth * 2, ' ' ) 
          + $"{child.Name} (Directory: {child.IsDirectory})");

        PrintItems(child, depth + 1);
    }
}
```

You can use this like so:

```cs
var items = ReadFilesAndDirectories(@"C:/PickAFolder...");
PrintItems(items);
```